# How to make Chrome remember webpage position after going back?

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling

In IE, when I scroll down a webpage, click on an article to read it and then hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to go back - IE always remembers how far down on the page I was so I never have to re-scroll down every single time I go back.

However, this never works in Google Chrome! So inefficient.
How do I get Chrome to remember my position (where I was) on the previous page when I go back?

Comment: Keep in mind that hitting `backspace` is just a keyboard shortcut to go back to the previous page (in the browser history). [Scrollmark](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kofgleoimiobbakpnplbdddmkdgiephl/reviews?hl=en) extension did that - but it's outdated. `"This extension will remember your scroll position on a particular page, and restore it the next time you visit that page."`

Comment: @verve you're welcome to edit your question into something more useful and with less complaining, then your question could potentially be reopened.

Comment: @AlE., This looks more like **a question** disguised as a "rant". There's nothing wrong with stating that a browser is inefficient, especially when the prevailing opinion is that remembering scroll state is more efficient.

Comment: @Pacerier: The question was edited since I posted my comment. Perhaps you should look at the original and see just how "ranty" it was. Even so, my comment is now out of date because this is, indeed, a question.

Answer (score 1):

Update your google chrome to the latest build, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Confirmed on Chrome 22.0.1229.79

Comment: I'm on the latest build of Chrome as well (22.0.1229.79) on OS X Mountain Lion and I've noticed that the browser doesn't return to its previous scroll point when you hit `BACK` as well. It wasn't an issue on the latest version of Chrome on Windows 7 or 8.